# Update value of one field based on another

Tags: save, sitecore

I have a template two text fields. A user creates an item based on this template and enters content into the first text field.

On item save, I want to be able to manipulate that value, somehow, and write it to the second field when the item is saved.

I have read about 3 ways of doing this - item:saved, item:saving or item save rules engine. I'm looking for an explanation in the difference of these approaches and if you had to choose which one would you pick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Item Saved is an event fired after an item has been saved. I wouldn't use that because it will chain events once you want to update again the same item. There is ways to avoid that but I would rather use Item:Saving, which is fired before the item has been saved.

Rules engine, I don't know exactly how it would fit your needs.

A sample of a item saving that changes the item name prior to being saved:

```
public class ItemNameReplacementEventHandler
{
    /// Called when [item saving].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="args">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    public void OnItemSaving(object sender, EventArgs args){
        var item = GetContextItem(args);

        if (!ShouldChange(item))
            return;

        //do the replace
        Regex pattern = new Regex(this.ReplaceFromRegexPattern);
        string newName = pattern.Replace(item.Name, this.ReplaceToString);
        item.Name = newName;
    }
    private static Item GetContextItem(EventArgs args)
    {
        return Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
    }
}
```

Just change the value of a field, or in this case the item name, and it is enough.

The configuration is like this:

```
<events>
    <event name="item:saving">
        <handler patch:before="handler[@type='Sitecore.Tasks.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel']"
                         type="TYPE, ASSEMBLY" method="OnItemSaving">
        </handler>
    </event>
</events>
```